# Is there is full IDE available for writing apps on elementary OS?

Tags: programming

I'm opt1ckz (Mark), I knew Daniel from DeviantART and have followed Elementary since it was an Icon Theme/Firefox Skin. I am an old school developer from Windows, started with mIRC scripting believe it or not. I then taught my self Pascal (Delphi before the .net switch) and wrote my own IRC client. Now adays I write in VS/VSCode with c# and c++.

Anyway, that's a brief history of my development abilities. The only question that I have is, is there a good IDE to write apps in the native EOS language? I've tried to work in Scratch, also several plugins with other full IDE's but I'm looking for a fully integrated IDE to work not only on code but visuals as well. I was given the name "opt1ckz" way back on irc.msn by some friends (who later turned out to be LulSec, go figure right...) because my Dialogs, also my own programs we're visually beautiful. I could match and surpass Microshit's Forms. Cutting to the chase, I need a fully functional visual IDE to live up to my name's sake.

Thanks guys, I absolutely LOVE Elementary! I've been a user since 0.1 and always supported you guys on Launchpad.net.

```
                       - Mark (opt1ckz, The Makeshift Martyr)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the nightly version of Gnome Builder:

> I like to check in on the development of Gnome Builder from time to time, because for better or worse, I'm an IDE guy when it comes down to it. I make my living doing C# in Visual Studio...can't help it. In the past Gnome Builder hasn't been either stable, or full featured enough for my Vala development needs.
>
> Anyways, I installed the latest Gnome Builder nightly build as per the instructions here and was able to open my existing Scratch/Code Vala project right out of the box. It builds, runs, and you even have a nice debugger built in. Really awesome.
>
> Up until this point, I had done all my dev work with Scratch/Code, but was really sore without a debugger. If you're an IDE guy like me, give it a shot. It may just turn the tide for you eOS apps in the future.
>
> Happy coding everyone!

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/7riddi/just_fyi_gnome_builder_nightly_works_great_for/

But then again, Cassidy in the official elementary OS blog says:

> we use Scratch on elementary OS to build elementary OS.

In: [Scratch is now elementary Code](https://medium.com/elementaryos/scratch-is-now-code-2838e03134c7)